# What was the "data dip" that Google reports for webmaster tools data on May 15th, 2016?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

The Google Webmaster panel index says:

> Update: As of 5/14/16, Index Status data precisely reflects the specific URL variant for your verified site (e.g., `http://www.example.com` data is distinct from `https://example.com`).

Is this saying the index count for `http://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` are now counted separately, and if so is it based on protocol or subdomain?

Clicking the `Learn More` link (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211453#indexed) brings me to a page that says

> **May 15, 2016**
>   A data anomaly caused a dip in the data on this day.

Searching `May 15th Google Index` brings back a variety of user experiences all showing on that date something happened. The results since then have been varied though. Our site since that day has had a +1.5 million index dip.

Is this a real issue or just a reporting bug? Searching `site:example.com` brings back the same number the webmaster panel has (so I'm presuming not a bug).

Comment: Google treats http and https as separate sites just as it treats any subdomain www or without as separate.  If your site is accessible via both means then you have duplicate content, unless your using canonical links and you have set your preferred site within Webmaster Tools. If you haven't already you should add all variations to Webmaster Tools, `HTTPS WWW` `HTTPS NON-WWW`, `HTTP WWW` and `HTTP NON-WWW`. You must use canonical links or a 301 redirect to avoid sites being treated as separate.

Comment: Ohhh, didn't realize the protocol was specific as well. Thanks, our canonicals are `<link rel="canonical" href="/dir/page-title" />` we'll have to move those to absolute. So it could just be that on 5/14 Google separated the index counts for `http` and `https`? The index count for `site:http://www.example.com` and `site:https://www.example.com` is the same

Comment: Google has _always_ counted `http` and `https` separately. (They are different URLs.) If the index counts for both are the same then it would suggest you are not canonicalising your URLs (as Simon suggests).

Comment: @chris85 For what it is worth, canonical links should always be absolute. From: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en - *Avoid errors: use absolute paths rather than relative paths with the rel="canonical" link element.*

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll go to work on this now. Perhaps the May 14th just separated the counts and made the issue prevalent.

Comment: I made the canonical absolute. I also added the secure paths to the webmaster panel but haven't noticed a difference in the number of indexed pages. The https pages all seem considerably lower then the non-secure versions, I was thinking they would be the same or the secure would be higher. Do they take time to populate (its been 10 days)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been stated in the comments above Google treats sites differently based on protocol as well as if they have different sub domains (including www and non www sites). what this means is that...

http://example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
http://some-other-sub.example.com

Are all treated as different sites for crawling and indexing purposes.

As a side note there was an unconfirmed update to Google's algorithm on the 10th May 2016, an update I add that Google has not announced or confirmed either, and so this error may have been due to that update as well. The message appears to have hit many other users as well around the same date.

Due to Google's lack of details on this incident there is no real way to know for certain if this was a temporary bug or if this was due to a change in the indexing algorithm. If it was a temporary bug then I would expect your sites index to return to normal, if not then chances are it has been adjusted by an algorithm change.

Additionally I note from your comment that you have canonical links on your site. You should ensure that your canonical links are an absolute URL not a relative path and that the root protocol and domain are the main ones that you want appearing in the Google index and that you want customers to access predominantly. In other words if you want the Google SERP to show your site as `https://www.domain.com/whatever` then you should make sure that all of your canonical links start with `https://www.domain.com/`.

Comment: The count for `https://www.example.com` and `http://www.example.com` are the same when searching with `site:` on Google. With the webmaster panel though there is a noticeable difference between the 2. Is there a way to use the `site:` search feature to get a live view of the index count? Currently we wait +1 week to see the changes we're trying to take affect.

Comment: No there is no way through search to do what you are requesting. The `site:` flag is meant to allow the searcher to filter results to one site only. Additionally the index count isn't quite live, what happens is the crawler gets a copy of your page, stores a cache of it on Google's caching servers. Then the next step is that the indexing server go through the page and evaluate the appropriate context-specific keywords and add them to Google's inverted index (A generalisation of the process but basically accurate). This can take anywhere up to 2+ weeks to be completed, so not live at all.